# (When) are questions asking for checklists appropriate?

Tags: discussion, not-constructive, not-a-real-question

Are any questions asking for checklists appropriate for Stack Overflow, i.e. neither "not constructive" nor "not a real question"?

If the answer is "it depends", please explain with examples what it depends on.

[Referenceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16882710).

Comment: I don't think that's a good example, it's a horrible question... _"Could you please give me all the checklist needed in testing."_, i.e. do my work for me.

Comment: That example seems more like NARQ than NC so I closed it as such.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Now I'm wondering whether any "check-list question" is **not** 'not a real question'.

Comment: @Dukeling what on earth do you mean by "checklist question"?  That question wasn't a bad question because it had the word "checklist" in it.

Comment: @djechlin A "check-list question" means one asking for a check-list.

Comment: Can you give an example of one you think should be constructive?

Comment: @djechlin That's part of what I'm asking.

Comment: Rephrased:  What do you think would make one constructive? Do you understand why your linked question was not constructive?

Comment: @djechlin IMO it was not constructive because it was asking for a check-list, which would follow the same argument as a question asking for a book suggestion. So I don't think any such question can ever be constructive.

Comment: Can you clarify why you are asking this, what is your goal or problem you're trying to solve? There may exist checklist questions that are constructive, if the context is very narrow and it is possible to give a canonical answer - even if we can't think of an example.

Answer (score 2):

Asking for a checklist is, in itself, not essentially nonconstructive.  This question could have easily been revised to say "give me some suggestions" instead of asking for a "checklist," which is why I'm so perplexed you're caught up on the checklist-ness.  Anyway, it's hard for me to imagine how such a question could ever be constructive, probably because once a "checklist" question has enough information to be constructive, it's probably not going to be asked as a checklist anymore.

Here's an example of one of my questions that you may liberally think of as checklist done right:  [Is git pull --rebase safe if you are in a centralized model and never push force?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284514/is-git-pull-rebase-safe-if-you-are-in-a-centralized-model-and-never-push-force)

Essentially I had "worked out" the checklist myself and wanted to learn if my reasoning was *complete*.  If the OP in a checklist question had enough knowledge to know that there were exactly, say, 3 or 5 things to check for, then this may be passable - but you would note that in that case the OP wouldn't ask for a checklist, they would probably word and frame it much differently.

But raw checklist?  Facilitates a lot of incomplete answers, voting based on which answers one likes rather than which answers are correct, etc.